How to remove parent keys from a nested dictionary if child keys are empty without modifying the original dictionary?
I have a nested dictionary for which I need to remove parent keys if some predefined child keys are empty. For example, consider the following dictionary d:
d = {
    'outer_key_1': {
        'class': 'a_class',
        'items': {
            'A': {   # <- this key should be removed
                'item': 'A',
                'tags': [],
                'count': 3
            },
            'B': {
                'item': 'B',
                'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2'],
                'count': 5
            }
        },
        'type': 1,
        'attic': 1
    },
    'outer_key_2': {...},
}

I want to remove the parent keys where the child key tags is empty. In this example, I want to remove the inner key A because the tags key under 'items'['A'] is empty. I have a solution that modifies the original dictionary in place:
def remove_parent_key(d, check_key):
    for key, value in list(d.items()):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            if check_key in value:
                if value[check_key] in ('', [], {}, None):
                    del d[key]
            else:
                remove_parent_key(value, check_key)

However, I need to keep the original dictionary unchanged and return a new dictionary with the desired modifications.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Apply copy.deepcopy() to the dict, apply your in-place modification code to the copy?

Yes. But the dictionary can be large and in that case I would have to delete one of the copies myself, whereas in a function the references to the returned dictionary would be deleted when the function exits (in principle). Additionally, it would be nice to be able to use something like remove_parent_key(remove_parent_key(d, 'some_key'), 'another_key').
